# OCCI in Oracle database - Couldn't find entry point of procedure OCIPIsDescRebuilt in OCI.dll library

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, visual-studio-2010, oracle11g

I've decided to connect my C++ game with Oracle database using `OCCI` (Oracle C++ Call Interface). I've finally managed to compile my program with `occi.h` included but now, when I run the program, I get the message:

```
Couldn't find entry point of procedure OCIPIsDescRebuilt in OCI.dll library.
```

Here is a small part of my code in which I try to connect with database:

```
#include <occi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
using namespace oracle::occi;

int main()
{
    Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
    Connection *conn = env->createConnection("system", "password","localhost:1521");

    cout << "Podaj nick gracza nr 1: ";
    cin >> nick[1];
    cout << "Podaj nick gracza nr 2: ";
    cin >> nick[2];

    Statement *stmt = conn->createStatement();

    stmt->executeUpdate("INSERT INTO uzytkownicy VALUES('1','A',nick[1])");
    stmt->executeUpdate("INSERT INTO uzytkownicy VALUES('1','B',nick[2])");

    ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM basket_tab");
    cout << "The basket has:" << endl;

    while (rs->next())
    {
        string fruit = rs->getString(1);     // get the first column as string
        int quantity = rs->getInt(2);        // get the second column as int

        cout << quantity << " " << fruit << endl;
    }

    env->terminateConnection(conn);
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);
}
```

I use MS Visual Studio 2010 and Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 (11.2). Apart from Oracle® C++ Call Interface Programmer's Guide, 11g Release 2 (11.2), I also used materials from these sites:

- [Mark Williams Blog](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/07/getting-started-with-occi-windows.html)
- [This Thread Blog](http://thisthread.blogspot.com/2011/07/oracle-occi-for-visual-studio-2010.html)

How can I solve this problem? Maybe there is a simplier way (as for configuration) to connect with database using C++ program than through `OCCI`?

Comment: So you linked in the proper .lib file?  Is this the correct dll?  You can use the MS "depends" program to load the DLL and see all the entry points that are in it.

Comment: Actually I'm quite confused. Here there are available versions of OCCI:
[link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/occidownloads-083553.html)
I run computer on Windows 7 64x but my MS Visual Studio is 32-bit (x86). To me, it means that I should download 32-bit version of OCCI, but I may be wrong. Anyway, when I try to do the whole including and linking procedure for 64-bit files, I get a message from compilator, that "occi.h couldn't be found"... When you download any of these versions of OCCI, you'll notice that there is readme file inside. Funny thing is that it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Well, if you are using a 32-bit compiler, then I would expect you need to include/link the 32-bit headers/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of this error by copying the oci.dll file from the Oracle 12c Instant Client to the bin/Debug or bin/Release directory of my application so it would get loaded instead of the oci.dll that is in the default Oracle 11 client that gets installed.